# ActionS in Swing ContainerS (JFrameS etc)

Tags: java, swing, containers, action

It seems that while you can add ActionS to ComponentS, you can't add them to ContainerS such as JFrame, JApplet or JDialog. Since I could find nothing helpful on Google, I felt I should share my findings so people in the future don't have to waste too much time. Please feel free to add information if you think I missed something or let something out.

The solution lies in .getRootPane(), which will then allow you to add actions like so:

jframe.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("INSERT"), insertAction);

Hope this will be helpful to future generations.

Comment: not really a question.... more of a funky capital S

Comment: I followed the procedure outlined at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question because like I said, there wasn't anything to find on Google. As for the capital S, it's how the Sun Javadoc decided to point out that the S is for plural and not part of the class names.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can add Key Bindings to a JPanel. Its a Swing component.

I'm not sure that the "WHEN_FOCUSED" InputMap will work. Normally focus is on a component, not the root pane.

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of the default bindings and my simple example of using Key Bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I don't know where the JPanel came from, as I had the trouble with JFrame and JDialog - blame late night coding. The WHEN_FOCUSED map worked fine in my tests, although my test case was simplistic so the ANCESTOR map might be better in general.